# order by sql is returning some invalid value

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, sybase

I am facing a problem in case of order by query in sybase and that is happening only in one database but not in all. Please find the problem statement as below.

if i execute query 1 then the output result will be 0 records since no data available which satisfying this `dateTime <= 1423065608`. But if i execute query 2 then its returning some invalid value which is not present in the db.

Please help to understand why this problem is happening.

query 1: `select recordID from tbl_SysLog where (dateTime <= 1423065608)`

query 2: `select recordID from tbl_SysLog where (dateTime <= 1423065608) order by recordID ASC`

Thanks and Regards,
Naveen

Comment: check 2nd query to which database it is pointing to

Comment: where recordID is int type and its the primary key in the table

Comment: @ Ameya  thank u for your reply and its pointing to the same database

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? What data type is this `dateTime` column? Can you post the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the table `tbl_syslog`?

Comment: CREATE TABLE tbl_SysLog (
    recordID                    int                  NOT NULL ,
    dateTime                    int                  NOT NULL ,
    resultID                    int                  NOT NULL ,
    primary key (recordID)
) and the DBMS is "sybase"

Comment: what is the strange out;put you are getting ?

Comment: recordID    
 ----------- 
 730225310   --- this is the output if i use query 2: and this value is not present in the table and if i remove the  order by then result will be empty as below  recordID    
 ----------- 

 0 record(s) selected [Fetch MetaData: 1/ms] [Fetch Data: 0/ms]

Comment: Have you tried asc or desc at the end of the query? I recommend to use 'set showplan on' before you run the query to see the query plan.